# Why is searching for the empty string so fast?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I noticed that running

```
select * from cdr_data where rownum < 10 and customer_tag = ''
```

is significantly faster than

```
select * from cdr_data where rownum < 10 and customer_tag = 'a'
```

What could be the cause?

Edit: Using Oracle 11g. There is no entry where customer_tag has data 'a'. Just to be clear. I am using a company tool to make these queries.

Comment: It might depend on the TYPE of customer_tag.  And also on the DB -- which DB are you using?  What are the timing differences that you see?  What is table size?

Comment: When you added the SQL tag, a large suggestion was displayed that recommended you also add a tag for the specific DBMS you're using, as functionality and syntax between them differs. By choosing to ignore that suggestion, you've simply delayed getting an answer while we ask you **What specific DBMS are you using?** and wait for you to add a tag for it. Please do not ignore those sorts of suggestion; they're there for a reason. So **What specific DBMS are you using? Functionality and syntax between them differs, so having that information is relevant. Please [edit] to add a tag for that DBMS.**

Comment: the type of customer_tag is VARCHAR2(240). I'm not sure how to tell what DBMS this is. I think it's Oracle. The second query doesn't seem to end. The table size is massive.

Comment: You don't know what DBMS you're using? Stop and figure that out before you do anything else.

Comment: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production. I think that's the DBMS? Sorry, knowing this information is not something I've needed to know yet in the little time I've been here

Comment: @KenWhite Out of curiosity, what is one difference between different DBMS's that can make a difference to the issue I posted? I would have thought that all DBMS's treat strings (empty or not) in roughly the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quote from the Oracle documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements005.htm):

> Note: Oracle Database currently treats a character value with a length
>   of zero as null. However, this may not continue to be true in future
>   releases, and Oracle recommends that you do not treat empty strings
>   the same as nulls.

So your query of:

> select * from cdr_data where rownum < 10 and customer_tag = ''

is equivalent to:

> select * from cdr_data where rownum < 10 and customer_tag is null

One possible explanation: Perhaps Oracle can do an `is null` comparison faster than comparing two strings.

Comment: Running `select * from cdr_data where rownum < 10 and customer_tag is null` also doesn't seem to be returning a value (I'm just stuck waiting for a response) whereas `= ''` returns "no matches found" almost instantly

Comment: Sorry, my first comment was totally off. `select * from cdr_data where rownum < 10 and customer_tag is null` does return 9 entries, but `select * from cdr_data where rownum < 10 and customer_tag = ''` returns no matches found

Comment: Is it really equivalent to `is null` and not `= null`?

Comment: I'm an idiot, and I probably should have noted this a long time ago. I am using a company tool to make these queries. Maybe the tool itself is making a distinction between null and ''?

Comment: That could be the problem. What happens when you run this directly from SQL Plus or some other ad hoc SQL tool?

Comment: I don't think it's possible for me to make these queries without using company tools at the moment. I used another tool with similar results. But I'll assume you're correct with your initial answer